# How to show new Slack messages in GNOME notifications?

Tags: gnome, notification, slack

How do I show new Slack messages in GNOME notifications?

Answer (score 4):

As I understand, this is not currently possible, and is due to a mismatch between how Electron (the framework the Slack app uses on PCs) performs notifications, and how FreeDesktop Notification Spec defines behavior of certain notifications.

The same issue also exists with other Electron apps, such as [Mattermost](https://github.com/mattermost/desktop/issues/539).